# Saving file path imported by file.choose () in R

Tags: r

I'm looking for a way to save file path of a file that's imported to R using file.choose(). Suppose I have a function that imports a csv file and saves the first N columns in a new file in the same directory as the original file.Something like this:

```
Split<-function(N,...){

data<-read.csv(file.choose(),header=T)

write.csv(data[,1:N],paste("FILE PATH","newdata.csv"),row.names=F)}
```

I want to have the "FILE PATH" to be the same as where the original csv file is located. Because of the mechanism of file.choose() I couldn't find a way to save file path in an object within the function and use it for "FILE PATH".

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: You may want `list.files()` instead.  `file.choose()` is more for interactive use.

Comment: @RichardScriven the aim to to enable user to select a file interactively but the function is also supposed to save the output in the same directory. So, how `list.files()` may help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two functions [dirname](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/basename.html) and [file.path](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/file.path.html) from {[base](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/00Index.html)} might be helpful in this case.

```
> file_user <- file.choose()
> file_user
[1] "C:\\Users\\ohyeah\\Desktop\\chinese.txt"
> path_user <- dirname(file_user)
> path_user
[1] "C:/Users/ohyeahg/Desktop"
> newfilename <- "myresult.csv"
> newfilepath <- file.path(path_user, newfilename)
> newfilepath
[1] "C:/Users/ohyeah/Desktop/myresult.csv"
> write.csv(iris, newfilepath)
>
# there is a new file 'myresult.csv' created in the same folder
# and it contains the iris dataset.
```

As you can see, the file separator has been changed from `\\`(windows) to `/`(linux), however, you can use the `sep` argument in `file.path` to customize it which works independent of platform.

---

If you need to access several files in that user selected directory maybe multiple times, it will be tedious to rebuild the absolute path every time. You can just simply set the working directory to be the user select folder and you can read or write with file names only.

```
> setwd(path_user)
> newfilename <- "myresult_new.csv"
> write.csv(iris, newfilename)
> head(read.csv(newfilename))
X Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Comment: @Amin, depending on your use case, you might want to think about change the working directory to the user selected one. In that case, you can omit the file path and just assign the filenames to read/write. That will be helpful if you need to read or write multiple times and it is a bit  tedious to rebuild absolute file path everytime.